# Operator applicable in XamMac but unapplicable in MonoMac

Tags: mono, xamarin, monodevelop, monomac, xamarin.mac

I am trying to compile a Xamarin.Mac project with Monodevelop+Monomac (3.0.5 from source).

I changed the reference from XamMac to MonoMac, and everything seems to be fine except this:

> Error CS0019: Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'MonoMac.Foundation.NSObject' and 'string' (CS0019)

The error occurs at a line `if (tableColumn.Identifier == "Name")` where `tableColumn` is a [NSTableColumn](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nstablecolumn_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Can I make this compile without modifying the code?
Or if I must modify the code, what is the best practice in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

surely....

```
 if (tableColumn.Identifier.Equals("Name"))
```

would be better?

Answer (score 0):

XamarinMac most likely has operator for ==  between NSString/NSObject and string. Either modify MonoMac source code to add the operator (nice chance to contribute to the community edition) or change your code to compare NSString("Name") instead of string.